# Finding right price from an index list with priority in excel

Tags: excel

I work in a world wide manufacturing company where we have warranty claims.

I need to make a list in Excel with priority that will find the right supplier => the right price for that warranty claim.

One claim/warranty repair could be made in an EU-country, but we may have suppliers in Asia/EU. Then I need to pinpoint the supplier in EU and their price, but if there isn't any supplier in EU then I need to find the supplier in Asia and pinpoint the price from them to the EU-repair.

I've managed to use XLOOKUP with multiple criteria (Part Number & Supplier). If it find the right supplier, it gives me a price but otherwise gives me "N/A"/"Null"/"0" if not found.
Instead of "N/A"/"Null"/"0" I want my formula to look for the next supplier or counter supplier in Asia/EU with an IF statement(?) according to priority list.

Priority list down below:

| Repair Country | PRIO 1 supplier | PRIO 2 supplier | PRIO3 supplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EU | **DE2FP** | C2CUL | "find it manually"/ N/A |
| Asia | CNH23 | **DE2FP** | CN342 |

=XLOOKUP(H2&E2;'Part Number List'!G:G&'Part Number List'!I:I;'Part Number List'!Q:Q;"N/A";0;"N/A")

Translated: XLOOKUP(PartNumber & Supplier; PartNumber from Index List & Supplier from Index List; Price Per Unit; Exact match; Not Found Statement)

I hope this makes sense and thanks for answer.
The priority is the problem here, I'm not sure how to formulate my XLOOKUP-formula to make it look for the next price from another supplier if there isn't an exact match.

Comment: Have a look whether FILTER is an alternative to show you the information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759 basically, you could get a list of appropriate suppliers sorted according to priority

Comment: Show your input then output. Question is quite unclear.

Comment: Tried putting in an input/output but the tables couldn't be viewed and my file is over 200k rows. Not sure how to demonstrate it in a pedagogic way.